# How to crop characters of a String?

Tags: java

What tools are available to crop a specified number of characters off of either the front of, the back of, or both the front and back of a provided string of characters?

ie String = "Supernatural is the best tv show";

and we cropped of the front by 6 characters
now we have... "atural is the best tv show";

or we could have cropped the front & back by 6 characters
now we have... "atural is the best t"

Comment: Look at the `String` and `StringBuilder` javadoc.

Comment: Google the following phrase "java api String"

Comment: Basically `substring`, but you will have to check first to make sure the string is long enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cut off first x characters:
`str.substring(x)`

To cut off last x characters:
`str.substring(0,str.length()-x)`

To cut off first and last x characters:
`str.substring(x,str.length()-x)`

See the two [String.substring()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) methods.

Your example:

```
int x = 6;
String str = "Supernatural is the best tv show";
System.out.println(str.substring(x));
System.out.println(str.substring(0,str.length()-x));
System.out.println(str.substring(x,str.length()-x));
```

Console output:

> atural is the best tv show
>
> Supernatural is the best t
>
> atural is the best t

Answer (score 2):

Read this: [String API Page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Focus on the methods named `substring`

You may find this useful: [Apache Commons Lang StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.4/)

Again, focus on the methods named `substring`

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be using the existent `String#substring` method:

```
String msg = "ONETWOTHREE";

System.out.println(msg.substring(3));    // TWOTHREE
System.out.println(msg.substring(0, 6)); // ONETWO
System.out.println(msg.substring(3, 6)); // TWO
```

Reference:

- [String#substring(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29)
- [String#substring(int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: Yeap, my mistake. Fixed ;)

Comment: btw, to embed a link you can do [words](URL)

Comment: I know, I put them separately because they are actually two methods ;)

Comment: Ah I saw an edit where it looked like you were trying to unsucessfully, so thought I'd just mention it!

Comment: Oh I see. I've tried to put the link reference inside the code block (the `String#substring`). It didn't work and I noticed that they were actually two methods.